# Link in PHP mail does not send the right link

Tags: php, email, outlook

I am sending a mail with php and I have included a link using this code:

```
$message = "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n"."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n";
$message .= "<a href='www.stackoverflow.com'>Click.</a>\n\n";
```

The link does get sent in the email but when I click on the link in Outlook it will open in IE and it goes to `res://ieframe.dll/syntax.htm#www.stackoverflow.com` instead of the `www.stackoverflow.com`.

However when I hover my mouse over the link it will show the correct link on the bottom of the page, take a look at this:

[image]

(The printscreen removes the mouse but in the pic I was hovering my mouse on the link.)

Is there something wrong with my code or could this be an Outlook issue? If anyone knows what could be wrong it would be great!

Comment: set your browser as default browser and use this code: `href='http://www.stackoverflow.com'` use the http:// in url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `http://` before the link.

Otherwise it will be appended to the end of the current url.

Comment: Kinda dumb I didn't even think of trying this^^ Thnx anyway and I will accept the answer when I'm able to!